# Ajax link on a new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a web application using ajax and faced with the problem.
After loading the file browser address line does not change.

How can I greate link of page  and write it to a browser address line when ajax load function whill be done?

```
<div id='home-wrap'>
  <div id='ajax-accept'></div>

  <div id='menu-wrap'>
    <div id='menu'>
      <div id='info' class='category-holder'>ИНФОРМАЦИЯ</div>
      <div id='contacts' class='category-holder'>КОНТАКТЫ</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div> 


$('#info').click(function(){
    $('#ajax-accept').load('http://beardhouse.com.ua/sources/pages/informacia.html');
});
```

Comment: If you want the address to change, why use ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the JavaScript history api.
Check the following urls

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Also check

http://caniuse.com/#search=history

Seb

Answer (score 1):

**Ajax** mean that your request will load without refresh your page it's mean that your link will not changed when you request the new link/page, if you need to open your link in a new windows/tab (change requested link) you can use href instead of ajax, check example below:

```
<div id='home-wrap'>
<div id='ajax-accept'></div>

<div id='menu-wrap'>
<div id='menu'>
  <a href="http://beardhouse.com.ua/sources/pages/informacia.html" target="_blank" id='info' class='category-holder'>ИНФОРМАЦИЯ</a>
  <div id='contacts' class='category-holder'>КОНТАКТЫ</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update location.href value for redirecting to new page.